# How to use humanoid_localization with stereo cameras?

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, stereo-camera, stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I started using the humanoid_localization node for localizing my robot using stereo cameras.
I give the node a sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 as input, but I don't provide any sensor_msgs/LaserScan.
According to the humanoid_localization wiki page, this setup should be fine.

I am able to run the node and the particle filter is working, but for every particle filter update, the following error gets printed on the console hundreds of times:

```
ERROR: Raycasting in direction (0,0,0) is not possible!
```

The error message is generated when calling the `castRay` function in the file humanoid_localization/src/RaycastingModel.cpp.

What am I missing to have the node running without errors?
Do I need to create a "fake" LaserScan message from my stereo image data to get rid of the errors?
Do I need to change the parameter setting in my launch file?

Reading a paper from the authors of the humanoid_localization algorithms, I found out that they implemented a setup similar to mine using a depth camera. So the code has been used with cameras only, but I could not find out which adaptations were necessary. See:

> Maier, D.; Hornung, A.; Bennewitz, M.,
> "Real-time navigation in 3D
> environments based on depth camera
> data," Humanoid Robots (Humanoids),
> 2012 12th IEEE-RAS International
> Conference on , vol., no., pp.692,697,
> Nov. 29 2012-Dec. 1 2012

My setup:

- ROS fuerte
- Ubuntu 12.04
- stereo cameras fixed on wheeled robot

Extract of my launch file:

```
        <!-- Load map from octomap_server -->
    <node pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node" name="octomap_server"
    args="$(find nav)/maps/3D/track3_2014-02-18_image_proc_pc_tallmap.bt" output="screen" >
    </node>
    
    <!-- Localization -->
    <node pkg="humanoid_localization" type="localization_node" name="humanoid_localization" output="screen" >
        <remap from="point_cloud" to="/stereo_odometer/point_cloud" />      
        <param name="odom_frame_id" value="/odom" />
        <param name="base_frame_id" value="/base_link" />
        <param name="global_frame_id" value="/map" />
        <param name="num_particles" value="2000" />
        <param name="use_raycasting" value="true" />    
        <param name="use_imu" value="false" />
        <param name="base_footprint_id" value="/base_link" />
    </node>
```

**EDIT:** (for AHornung's answer)

I was using humanoid_navigation code downloaded from the APT repo ros-fuerte-humanoid-navigation.
Now, I downloaded the recent version of humanoid_navigation from GitHub, ran the humanoid_localization node and had the same issues as before.

The point cloud input for the humanoid_localization node has no NaNs.
I am not sure what other values could be invalid as input... could points in the origin (0,0,0) cause the error?

The width of my point cloud is 1 and the height is unequal to 1, so it seems to be ordered.

An extract of my console output:

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[saved_map/octomap_server-1]: started with pid [26692]
[ INFO] [1392965933.527639300]: Publishing latched (single publish will take longer, all topics are prepared)
[ INFO] [1392965933.601608621]: Octomap file /home/aes002/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/trunk/gator/nav/maps/3D/track1_2014-02-18_image_proc_pc.bt loaded (772778 nodes).
process[saved_map/humanoid_localization-2]: started with pid [26763]
[ INFO] [1392965933.779107102]: Requesting the map from /saved_map/humanoid_localization/octomap_binary...
[ INFO] [1392965933.848516881, 1392354124.777533329]: Sending binary map data on service request
process[saved_map/rviz-3]: started with pid [26867]
[ INFO] [1392965933.963886245]: Occupancy map initialized with 772778 nodes (61.10 x 39.00 x 2.70 m), 0.100000 m res.
[ WARN] [1392965933.977203542]: Frame ID of "initialpose" () is different from the global frame /map
[ INFO] [1392965933.977417430]: Pose reset around mean (0.000000 0.000000 0.320000)
[ WARN] [1392965933.983373819]: Failed to subtract base to odom transform, will not publish pose estimate: Frame id /odom does not exist! Frames (1): 
[ INFO] [1392965933.983481518]: Initialization of 50 particles took 0.00628427s (=0.000125685s/particle)
[ INFO] [1392965933.991816628]: NaoLocalization initialized with 50 particles.
[ WARN] [1392965934.152648624, 1392354124.958635337]: Message from [/stereo_odometer] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [camera]. Resolved locally to [/camera].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ INFO] [1392965935.092718408, 1392354125.526207845]: PointCloudGroundFiltering done. Added 248 non-ground points and 14 ground points (from 18). Cloud size is 262
[ INFO] [1392965935.092938381, 1392354125.526207845]: OdomTransformTemporal took 0.00014625s 
ERROR: Raycasting in direction (0,0,0) is not possible!ERROR: Raycasting in direction (0,0,0) is not possible!ERROR: Raycasting in direction (0,0,0) is not possible!
```

There are three warnings in the console output, the second one could be critical:

```
[ WARN] [1392965933.983373819]: Failed to subtract base to odom transform, will not publish pose estimate: Frame id /odom does not exist! Frames (1):
```

The error is created in humanoid_localization/src/HumanoidLocalization.cpp. The warning is printed once at the beginning of launching the node. I assume the warning is printed because `baseToMapTF`is not available while launching the node and therefore  `odomToMapTF` cannot be calculated.

I checked the TF tree using `tf view_frames` and visualized the frames in RViz. It turned out to be fine. So the warning mentioned above does not seem to be critical...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131236/how-to-use-humanoid_localization-with-stereo-cameras?/) by [RalphA](https://answers.ros.org/users/12191/ralpha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-02-20**:
Yes, points directly in the origin will be problematic! There is a filtering for min range in the code, but maybe that's not working properly in your case.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-02-20**:
The see the point clouds that will be used as measurements, you can subscribe to the topic `humanoid_localization/filtered_cloud`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to get rid of the issue.

I was using the following parameter setting:

```
<param name="base_frame_id" value="/base_link" />
```

By setting the `base_frame_id` to any other frame not coinciding with `/base_link`, the issue could be fixed.

For my system, the `/base_link`  lies on the map ground level. However, the ground level does not seem to be the issue. I initialized the system with `/base_link` lying above and below ground level and I was still getting the error

```
ERROR: Raycasting in direction (0,0,0) is not possible!
```

It seems like another property of `/base_link` was causing the issue.

---

Originally posted by [RalphA](https://answers.ros.org/users/12191/ralpha/) with karma: 36 on 2014-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1